# My first is in dare but never in fear / My second's in dark and also in clear

Tags: riddle

This is another riddle, I thought it might be fire, but some things don't fit.

> My first is in dare but never in fear,
> My second's in dark and also in clear,
> My third a shadow as well as in cave,
> My fourth is in gold and also in grave,
> My fifth is in cold as well as in hot,
> My sixth is in sun but not in spot,
> My whole enjoys a fiery feast,
> Look and discover a mythical beast.

What is the answer?

---

EDIT:

And I have been asked other riddles with the same structure... What does the "my first", "my second", "my third"... refer to? Does it mean something like "my first *clue*"?

Comment: This is a common type of riddle you will probably come upon time after time. As fljx shows in their answer, in each case the ordinal ('my first/second/third...') refers to an individual **letter**. Each line gives you a way to find a single letter for spelling out the solution word, by saying one of (i) the letter appears in *both* of two particular words, (ii) the letter appears in *neither* of two particular words, or (iii) the letter appears in *one particular word but not the other*, where in each case the 'particular words' are specified in the line (like 'dare' and 'fear' above).

Comment: Thank you! Why don't you make it an answer?

Comment: No worries, happy to help. Really it's just a clarification on the extra question in your edit - the riddle here appears to be the main 'meat' here. And I think fljx has already demonstrated this in action in their answer, even if not spelled out exactly like my comment above. Have a good day :)

Comment: I've added the extra detail to my answer. Hopefully it makes things clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> **Dragon**

Because:

> This is a simple acrostic, where most of the lines are of the form:
>  "My {nth letter} is in one/both/neither of two words"
>
>  In this case there are only one or two possibilities for each line:
>
> > My first is in **d**are but never in fear,
> >  My second's in da**r**k and also in clea**r**,
> >  My third a sh**a**dow as well as in c**a**ve,
> >  My fourth is in **g**old and also in **g**rave,
> >  My fifth is in c**o**ld as well as in h**o**t,
> >  My sixth is in su**n** but not in spot,
>
> And if we put those letters in order, we get "dragon", which is defined by the final two lines:
>
> > My whole enjoys a fiery feast,
> >     Look and discover a mythical beast.